# Checking SSL certificate value upon springboot application initialization

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I have secured my SpringBoot application with SSL using the following properties in the application.yaml file:

```
 ssl:
    enabled: true
    key-store-type: JKS
    key-store: classpath:keystore/keystore.jks
    key-store-password: 
    key-password: 
    key-alias:
```

I need to verify every time I start the SpringBoot application if the keystore.jks file exists and if not I need to download it.

What is the way to do it? is it possible?